# Avoid new tabs on Ctrl+Enter(Click) in Opera

Tags: javascript, tabs, opera, enter, ctrl

There is a lot of websites that use <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> for sending web forms. 
But in Opera, since [11.50 build 1018](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2011/05/27/fixes-and-improvements-on-demand-plug-in-sitepref-ctrl-click-support), this hotkey sends a form into a new background tab.

And Opera Next (12.50) even opens **several** new background tabs!
The sample code looks like this:

```
<form method="post" id="form">
    <textarea id="text"></textarea><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" /> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#text').keypress(function(event){
            if (event.ctrlKey && (event.which == 10 || event.which == 13)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation(); 
                event.ctrlKey = false;
                $('#submit').click();
            }
        });

        $("#submit").click(function(event){
            event.ctrlKey = false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Link to check out http://jsfiddle.net/8pYsv/

How can I avoid this behaviour? As Opera user, not as a website admin.

There's no config option in Opera for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd>, and `event.ctrlKey = false;` not working.

Only replacing `$("#submit").click()` with `$("#form").submit()` helps.

But there are many websites that will not change their code just for Opera..

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I've never come across a site where you need to do ctrl+enter to submit, could you give an example?

Comment: Well, it's not a primary action, just an additional option (shortcut) to submit the form. You still can do that by clicking the "submit" button. I've seen a lot examples in russian, but can't remember any in english for now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you key-combination in Opera's settings:

```
Ctrl-F12 
-> Shortcuts
-> Keyboard Setup 
-> Edit 
-> Type 'background'
-> Edit or delete the desired key combination.
```

Comment: I've already tried it, it works only for `Enter shift ctrl` but not for `ctrl+click`.
There's no way to setup shortcuts for mouse buttons.
And since we using `click()` event to submit the form, it will still open a new background tab on `ctrl+enter`.